# How can I search for a record multiple models below?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have models A,B,C,D. A model has multiple records of B, B of C and C of D.

I wanted to know if there is any way that I can go from A to D with a cleaner way than going from A to B... recursivly to D, making a huge and heavy code.

I was wondering if its possible to write something like

```
aa = A.something
if aa.bs.cs.ds.where(:status=>1).any?
 ...
```

I don't know how to title this better so maybe misleading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, use has-many-through:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs
  has_many :cs, :through => :bs
  has_many :ds, :through => :cs
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
  has_many :cs
end

class C < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :b
  has_many :ds
end

class D < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :c
end
```

Now you can get all of the `ds` for an `a` (filtered by status of each `d`) by calling:

```
a.ds.where(status: 1)
```

And you can call `exist?` or any of the query API calls as you would on any ActiveRelation object.  Note that all of this assumes that you are trying to work on `ds` related to a *single* `a` record.  If you are working on a collection of `a` records (such as a scoped ActiveRelation), you'll need to take a slightly different approach in getting the result - let me know if this is something you require.